# cloud messaging for windows phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Is their any cloud messaging services for windows phone.
just Like Google Cloud Messaging for Android.
google provid GCM http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yah its called WNS (Windows Push Notification Services).  You can send out messages(push notifications) from the cloud to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Microsoft has WNS and MPNS.

WNS works for Windows 8 devices, and MPNS is for Windows Phone devices.

[MPNS Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[WNS Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx)

Comment: By the way, if you need to implement the WNS provider you could use this library: http://fernandospr.github.io/java-wns/